# Non-breaking space is replaced by many browsers for xml 1.0 ISO-8859-1

Tags: html, xml, character-encoding

I came across a page recently http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/S/SNAFU-principle.html, on IE, Chrome, Forefox (Windows 7 and Android) it has spaces between words in many places replaced by `?`.

By hex view in notepad++ and web search I've found these `?` are replacement characters in case of error (unknown symbol). I've opened the page while sniffing by `Fiddler` to check original contents as initial saving of page resulted in different symbols in a file from different browsers, and confirmed that symbols are xA0 (non-breaking space), as far as I've read correctly put for document with that encoding `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>`.

When I saved body of response from fiddler and opened it, the non-breaking spaces were displayed correctly in browser as spaces. Please help to understand why if this page is loaded from the web, it is displayed with `?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content-type header in the HTTP response `text/html; charset=utf-8` is trumping the xml declaration encoding. xA0 is not valid for UTF-8, it needs to be the pair `{ xC2, xA0 }` for a non-breaking space.

Comment: Thank you. Why could that happen? The page as I understand was made long ago, could it give a glue?

Comment: That would be down to the configuration of the web server probably.

Comment: That header trumps - is it in html specification?

Comment: Kind of. As far as I know, for a resource with a content-type of text/html, the xml declaration encoding is ignored. The priority is BOM > HTTP header > http-equiv meta element.

Comment: The specification for that is partly in the html specification [8.2.2.2. Determining the character encoding](https://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#determining-the-character-encoding) and partly in the [mime sniffing standard](https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/) specification

Comment: HTTP and HTML are pretty much separate specifications.  If the HTTP header is wrong, it's wrong. HTML rules apply when the character encoding has not already been communicated.

Comment: @ Tom Blodget, @Alohci, In response headers it's written Apache. I've read https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html. Do I correctly undestand that to fix the issue the owner of web page can add `AddDefaultCharset off` to `.htaccess` file of folder with such pages? [provided `AllowOverride FileInfo` is written in main config of Apache.]

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov - Just turning off the default charset may be insufficient. Because in `text/html` the xml declaration is ignored, the browser has no information on what charset to use, and will make a guess based on where in the world the browser is. So in the US it might work fine, and the same page in China might not. The .htaccess file should really be set up to positive identify the file as either ISO-8859-1 or WIN1252.

Comment: Thank you. AFAIK the author/owner of site is experienced one. The page dates 2003. Why he included `xml` tag, but no `meta charset` on the page? Maybe how the web worked was that different years ago?

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov - Well, the file looks like a failed attempt to use XHTML. (Web devs did a lot of that circa 2003) There was much misunderstanding at the time about what was and wasn't XHTML. Because the browser that mattered then was IE, and IE didn't support XHTML, a lot of pages were written as if they were XHTML, but actually treated by browsers as normal HTML. That doesn't explain why the author thought it was OK. My guess is that the page worked on its server originally, but at some point was moved to a different server, or the server was reconfigured and the page not rechecked.